# webapi sql performance of query comparison

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api2

In terms of speed of execution, from webapi2 all things being equal, which method would be run faster?

OPTION 1
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery("dbo.myStoredProcedure").ToList();

OPTION 2
var query = db.table1.where(x =>x.email) == targetEmail.select(c => new PortfolioPerfomance)

Basically option1 I wrote the sql stored procedure myself, and option2 I let the models in EF do the appropriate relations.  The queries are much more complicated than this but I am just trying to understand the concepts of which would be faster.

thanks!!

Comment: why not run a test and see?

Comment: what would be the most accurate way to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an EF thing, no matter if you are using web api or not.

But, for bulk updates where you're updating massive amounts of data, a stored procedure will always perform better than an ORM solution because you don't have to marshal the data over the wire to the ORM to perform updates.

Also, if queries are complex, stored procedures are faster than Entity Framework when it need to retrieve massive amounts of data.

Keep in mind that both options will run faster if you have a a proper DB design.

Check this article for some tips to improve WEB API performance: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Tips-And-Tricks-To-Improve-WEB-API-Performance/

Also check this one to improve stored procedures: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/improve-stored-procedure-performance-in-sql-server-store-procedure-performance/

Comment: thanks.  I think my issue might start with proper db design.  do you know the most efficient way to test?

Comment: You must check this link about Integration Tests:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Also, read this article about database testing:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/11/27/dot-net-core-testing/